# Cannot access Azure DevOps Organisation website using Microsoft Account Login after connecting organisation to Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure-devops

I have a single Microsoft Account login which I use to access my personal Azure account (portal.azure.com) and my personal Visual Studio/DevOps account (e.g. myid.visualstudio.com or dev.azure.com/myid).  I was playing around in the DevOps Oragisation Settings and stupidly decided to connect my DevOps organisation to my Azure Active Directory as a test (which I did successfully).  However, as I only had one user in my DevOps Organisation (me) which used a Microsoft Account to login to the DevOps Organisation website, I can no longer access my Visual Studio/DevOps organisation as I get the following error:

401 - Uh-oh, you do not have access.
Your account,  is not authorized to view this page. Make sure the URL is correct and your account has access. View a list of your organizations here. You may request access by contacting the admin.

I understand why this is the case, but my question is, is there anyway to reverse this mistake?  Although I can still login to my Microsoft Account, this Microsoft Account no longer has permission to see the DevOps Organisation.  Have I just lost access to this DevOps Organisation forever?  I realise I can create a new one, but it's annoying as I'd have to pick a different name for the new organisation when what I really wan't is to re-associate the existing organisation to my existing microsoft login.

Anyway, I hope that makes sense.  I realise it was a stupid thing to do and that there's probably no way back, but thought I'd ask the experts on here just in case.

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot access Azure DevOps Organisation website using Microsoft Account Login after connecting organisation to Azure Active Directory

You need to open a support case on the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) and they can help you out.

They could disconnect your devops org from the AAD.

Hope this helps.